# Segmentation fault when calling getDocument using xerces for c++

Tags: c++, xerces, xerces-c

Good day. I have parser.h a sample.cpp(as parent node) and main.cpp. Im getting
segmentation fault in getting getDocument. Can someone help me... Here's my code:

**parser.h**

```
int Parser::Load(const char* xmlFile) {  
    try {  
        XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();  
    }  
    catch (const XMLException& toCatch) {  
        char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.getMessage());

        cout << "Error during initialization! :\n"  
             << message << "\n";  

        XMLString::release(&message);  
        return 1;  
    }

    XercesDOMParser* parser = new XercesDOMParser();  
    parser->setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);  
    parser->setDoNamespaces(true);  
    ErrorHandler* errHandler = (ErrorHandler*) new HandlerBase();  
    parser->setErrorHandler(errHandler);  

    try {  
        parser->parse(xmlFile);  
    }
    catch (const XMLException& toCatch) {  
        char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.getMessage());  

        cout << "Exception message is: \n"  
             << message << "\n";  

        XMLString::release(&message);  
        return -1;  
    }  
    catch (const DOMException& toCatch) {  
        char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.msg);  

        cout << "Exception message is: \n"  
             << message << "\n";  

        XMLString::release(&message);  
        return -1;  
    }
    catch (...) {  
        cout << "Unexpected Exception \n";  
        return -1;  
    }  
}
```

**sample.cpp**

```
void Sample::getXmlNodes(ParseXml* xmlParser){  
    map<std::string, std::string> attribList;  
    xmlParser->xmlDoc = xmlParser->parser->getDocument();  
    xmlParser->xmlNode = xmlParser->xmlDoc->getFirstChild();  
    attribList = xmlParser->getNodeAttribute(xmlParser->xmlNode);  
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "parser.h"  
#include "sample.cpp"

int main(int argc,char **argv){  
    const char* xmlString="sample.xml";  
    Parser* xmlObj;  
    Sample sampObj;

    xmlObj->Load(xmlString);  
    sampObj.getXmlNodes(xmlObj);  

    cout << "Done creating object..." << endl;  

    xmlObj->Cleanup();  
    return 0;  
}
```

I don't know what's wrong in my code ...

Answer (score 2):

You did not allocate memory for `xmlObj` objetc:

```
Parser* xmlObj;
Sample sampObj;  
xmlObj->Load(xmlString);   // SIGSEV here, you have no object to invoke
```

must be replaced by:

```
Parser xmlObj;  
Sample sampObj;  
xmlObj.Load(xmlString);
sampObj.getXmlNodes(&xmlObj);
```

Comment: still segfault during getting the getDocument. I tried
    XercesDOMParser* parser;
    DOMDocument* xmlDoc;
    xmlDoc = parser->getDocument(); 
I got 0 attribute count

Comment: Post your debug backtrace and complete example code. I don't understand what `XercesDOMParser* parser; DOMDocument* xmlDoc; xmlDoc = parser->getDocument()` means. But, if there is no more information, I assume you didn't alloc memory for a `XercesDOMParser` objetc, again, you used them without valid memory allocation. Why you use pointers? Is there any problem un something like `XercerDOMParser parser; DOMDocument *xmlDoc = parser.getDocument();`

Comment: Here's the code:
void Sample::getXmlNodes(ParseXml* xmlParser){
    map<std::string, std::string> attribList;
    XercesDOMParser* parser;
    DOMDocument* xmlDoc;
    xmlDoc = parser->getDocument();         
    //xmlParser->xmlDoc = xmlParser->parser->getDocument();  
    DOMNode* xmlNode = xmlParser->xmlDoc->getFirstChild();
    attribList = xmlParser->getNodeAttribute(xmlParser->xmlNode);
}

Comment: I think there's something wrong in Parser->parse(xmlString);
because I'm getting Null when im calling getDocument. I think I didn't pass the xmlObj->Load(xmlString); right. Any solution?

Comment: You can't use `parser` without allocating memory for it. Replace `XercesDOMParser* parser; DOMDocument* xmlDoc; xmlDoc = parser->getDocument()` by `XercesDOMParser parser; DOMDocument* xmlDoc; xmlDoc = parser.getDocument()`

Comment: I just put cout before and after of getDocument. segfault in getDocument. When I did like this xmlDoc = parser->getDocument(); I got 0 or null because I instantiate again XercesDOMParser* parser;

Comment: Again, and the last: don't use `parser->getDocument()`without allocating memory for `parser`. Read my comments

Comment: I did XercesDOMParser parser; its segfault there's no output even my strt printing